# How safe is to save properties files in assests or raw folders?

Tags: android

For the application I'm working on I was thinking to define few property files, something like: `debug.properties`, `beta.properties`, `release.properties`. These files mostly will contain urls to their corresponding environments. Depending of some flag I will set, the application will load the corresponding property file and read the values from there.

I was thinking to put these files in `assets` or `raw` resource folder, but after changing the extension from `.apk` to `.zip` of my application, I noticed that these file are accessible and readable.

If you had prior experience, what are the best practices for configuring different build environments in Android?
Is there a better place where I could put the properties files so they cannot be accessed?

Comment: They can be accessed no matter where you put them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same need in my app and found the same problem you found: It's to easy to open the apk and edit the properties files.
The solution I chose was to put those environment-specific properties in some Java source files. 
We have one Android project per environment. Each project is almost empty and refers to an Android Library that actually contains the app's code. Each Android project contains a Java file declaring its environment properties.
This seems counter-intuitive to use Java instead of properties file, but when fighting against piracy, all ways are good. The Java files can be obfuscated if you use Proguard. Even better, you can use Dexguard that can encrypt the strings in the Java source so that it will extremely hard to tamper the source and make the properties point elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Will take in consideration your answer.